# Can IPTV and Internet coexist?

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, ethernet, iptv

I need some help... I am living in Abu Dhabi and my ISP/IPTV provider is of little help with advanced technical issues/configurations.

My configuration... fiber modem with four ports/three active/one for internet and two for iptv.

I have a ethernet port in my living room that is currently connected to my STB wired directly to the fiber modem.  I would like to use that connection and add capability to connect my Samsung Smart TV, Samsung Home Theater and an HTPC simultaneously with the STB and avoid the wireless interference from my neighbors.

Equipment I currently have:

Asus RT-AC5300 - running Asuswrt Merlin set as my main wireless router, 
Asus RT-AC3200 - running Asuswrt Merlin set in wired AP, 
Asus RP-AC68U  - running Asus fw set as wired AP, 
Cisco SLM2008 (2) - 8 port Gigabit smart switch, 
Linksys LGS308(2) - 8-port Gigabit smart switch, 
Asus GX-D1081 v2  - 8 port Gigabit switch

How do I configure the router/switches/STB to use a single ethernet drop for both IPTV and internet in my living room?

I'm assuming I need to setup some vlan and trunking but am not familiar with the configuration.  I also understand that you need to do some tweaking to avoid Wifi issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't. You will need to use a separate wired connection for the internet in your living room. IPTV/STB connections are specially configured by the ISP (often they require their own specific DNS so they can download STB firmware updates and of course the program guides etc ...)

Comment: Disappointing... I thought you might be able to do it by setting up VLANs.

Comment: Some companies equipment will work with just a switch or hub, give it a try. And remember that just about nothing beats installing conduit, so you can run new lines easily in the future.